# Good Pattern for Class-Based "Task" Modules?

Tags: python, design-patterns, plugins, python-2.7, module

I'm attempting to design an easily-extendable/modular command-line application in Python (2.7). Each module is called a "task". There is one task per file, contained in a tasks/ directory, each containing a subclass of `Task`, and a `run()` method containing the code entry-point for a given task. As I want each "task file" to contain everything needed to register the task into the system. Each task contains metadata such as help, available arguments, authentication information, categories, etc. These are not just static properties--for example, the help system uses `Template`s to replace `$variable`s in help text.

Here's some example code:

```py
class TestTask(Task):
    description = "This task prints 'Hello world...' and exits."
    help = "Usage: $argv0 $task ...\n ..."

    def __init__(self, arguments=None):
        super(TestTask, self).__init__(description=self.description, arguments=arguments, help=self.help)

    def run(self):
        print("Hello world...")
```

So, then, how do we display help for a task? Or get a list of all tasks with descriptions? Well, we have to effectively scan the directory, import, load, and instantiate each task just to call `getHelp()` or `getDescription()` on it. Some of these tasks are fairly heavy. The loading time on a "list tasks" is over a second and is noticeable. I thought of caching it, but seems like overkill.

What's a cleaner/faster way to do this? Should I somehow cache the task metadata? I want this to be as dynamic as possible to ease development of tasks. I thought about an inner class containing metadata, but not sure. All of the task's `import`s would still have to be processed I believe, and I'm not clear on the proper way to share information between the "`Meta`" inner class and the containing `Task`. Newer to python so wondering if I'm missing something. How have you guys designed your plugin models? Thanks!

Comment: You might check out existing alternatives, particularly web frameworks, which often provide hooks. In terms of tasks specifically, the [`argparse` module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) lets you process arguments and provide useful help functions (even allows you to create subparsers to approximate something like git). it'll even let you get nicely formatted output.  What exactly would your package do that argparse doesn't?

Comment: Already using ArgumentParser--that's not the issue. Also not using a framework--this is the framework. If it helps, I can provide some more information in the question. My question is basically just about how to encapsulate the metadata in a way that is also performant. The "help" we're talking about isn't really just "Usage"--it provides pages of help for certain tasks. The point is the task must self-contain this metadata, at least in the file the task class is present in.

Comment: Sorry, I meant specifically that you might check out how other frameworks handle plugins, though I can't think of many that handle so many plugins that just importing them would be difficult.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at how Django uses "Meta", which gave me the idea to explore options besides caching. We're not talking about tons of tasks--maybe 30-50 tops? Can you think of any frameworks to check out besides Django?

Comment: Is it that important that you be able to add tasks dynamically? Could you keep a single file that's some sort of mapping between task, description and path? Django takes in a list of strings for import names. Maybe you could keep a file called "register.py" that handles that, and each folder could have its own `register.py` for its tasks.

Comment: I could, but it's one extra thing for a developer to worry about I guess. Maybe if that "register.py" or cache file was built by a simple "update-caches" task or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I think the claim

> we have to effectively scan the directory, import, load, and instantiate each task just to call getHelp()

is not obviously true. For example, a class need not have an instance instantiated (heavy) in order to obtain static, compile-time data. The loader is quite fast, especially if working from pre-parsed `.pyc` files.

I'm thinking about an example, but it is worth noting that

```
 import Task
 import TestTask
 print(TestTask.description)
```

should be nearly instantaneous relative to

```
 tt = TestTask()
 print(tt.get_help())
```

as no instance need be created in the former.

**added example**

I used the python standard library of 194 modules containing 112k source lines as an import speed test. The  abridged code is:

```
import abc
import aifc
import anydbm
import argparse
import ast
…
import webbrowser
import whichdb
import xdrlib
import xmllib
import xmlrpclib
import zipfile
print(tty.setraw.__doc__)
```

runs in 230ms on my underpowered laptop. The `__doc__` attribute is the function docstring which is bound to the name at import time, even when loading from pre-parsed `.pyc` files.

Comment: Right, I like the idea of doing this in static context. But I also need to seamlessly be able to do the same stuff from dynamic context. Can I easily use a classmethod in instance context? I'm also confused by your last sentence. How is no instance needed when tt = TestTask() creates an instance?

Comment: @msw's saying that you can access attributes of a class without instantiating it and that the first example is much faster (because it doesn't require instantiating a class) as compared to the second example.

Comment: Ah yeah, "latter" confused me :)

Comment: My final phrase had a bug in it (former != latter) which is why you might have been confused. Fixed, sorry.

Comment: Thanks! Great to know. It sounds like static context is where it's at. Are static method calls also fairly cheap?

Comment: It's hard to say without writing them and measuring them. It is possible for a static method to be as 'heavy' as you make it, but if you defer hard work until instance creation, then they are working with static data which, like the print in the example, is inexpensive attribute access. Be not too seduced by `@staticmethod` it doesn't do what people from other language backgrounds expect.